# Json.NET: Converting objects to DateTimeOffsets?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I'm making requests to an API service that returns dates as JSON in the following form:

```
{
     "dateCreated": {
        "date":8,
        "day":4,
        "hours":22,
        "minutes":44,
        "month":10,
        "nanos":241000000,
        "seconds":46,
        "time":1194590686241,
        "timezoneOffset":480,
        "year":107
     }
}
```

Here `time` is the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, so that's really the only property I want to pay attention to.

Would it be possible to write a custom Json.NET converter that deserializes this to something like

```
public class ApiResponse
{
    public ApiResponse(DateTimeOffset dateCreated)
    {
        DateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; }
}
```

(The converter would call `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds` on the object's `time` property.)

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public class ApiDateConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(DateTimeOffset) == objectType;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // What type is existingValue here? How do I get existingValue.time?
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**: Your `ApiDateConverter` can be completed by:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        dynamic jObject = JObject.Load(reader);

        return DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(jObject.time.Value);
    }
```

**Option 2**: Without using custom converter:

```
public class DateSerialized
{
    public int date { get; set; }
    public int day { get; set; }
    public int hours { get; set; }
    public int minutes { get; set; }
    public int month { get; set; }
    public int nanos { get; set; }
    public int seconds { get; set; }
    public long time { get; set; }
    public int timezoneOffset { get; set; }
    public int year { get; set; }
}

public class ApiResponse
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public DateTimeOffset DateCreated => DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(DateSerialized.time);

    [JsonProperty("dateCreated")]
    private DateSerialized DateSerialized { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly *possible* to write a Json.Net converter to translate the JSON directly into your domain object, but I don't advise this.

Instead, I would suggest you create a DTO (data transfer object) that mirrors the data:

```
public class DateDto
{
    public long Time { get; set; }
}
```

Then have Json.Net deserialize into this object.

Once you have that, you can create a pure .Net converter that maps the `DateDto` to a `DateTime` or whatever structure you want (supposing maybe that you are using the NodaTime library instead of .Net's `DateTime`).

By doing this, you save yourself the headache of implementing custom deserialization logic, and you're following the **S** in SOLID: Single Responsibility Principle.  You have an object whose purpose is solely to represent the data, and a converter to translate that into whatever your application uses.

It also increases the testability of your code.